# Trim comma from the start of a string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this arraylist

> Jakarta, the Capital City of Indonesia.
>
> ,Tokyo, the Capital City of Japan.
>
> ,Manila, the Capital City of Phillipines.

I want to remove the leading comma from Tokyo and Manila.
How should I write the universal code so that the it can detect whether a string is lead by comma and remove it??

Expected Result:

> Jakarta, the Capital City of Indonesia.
>
> Tokyo, the Capital City of Japan.
>
> Manila, the Capital City of Phillipines.

Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: (Also consider that the code that generates the List initially might be "at fault" and possibly adjusted.)

Comment: i am retrieving the list from a webpage and it is indeed not really neat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a regular expression:

```
for(int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
    String line = list.get(index);
    if (line != null && line.charAt(0) == ',') {
        line = line.replaceFirst("^,+");
        list.set(index, line); // Replace the string in the list
    }
}
```

It should work if you're using Java 5+

Comment: i'm using

replaceFirst(",","") instead of replaceFirst("^,+")

because it didn't work for me. But the rest of the code worked. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
String s = ",Manila, the Capital City of Phillipines.";
if( s.length() > 0 && s.trim().charAt(0) == ',' ) {
    s = s.substring(s.indexOf(',')+1).trim();
}
```

If you have to remove many commas, use while instead of if:

```
String s = " ,  ,,Manila, the Capital City of Phillipines.";
while( s.length() > 0 && s.trim().charAt(0) == ',' ) {
    s = s.substring(s.indexOf(',')+1).trim();
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer to work to work for multiple commas and for "". Thanks !

Comment: Just an example of why I prefer a regular expression in cases like this, even though the more manual ways will work.

Comment: at my first attempt using only charAt(0) == ',' and replaceFirst(",","") worked. Maybe this code will help for another cases. Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this one (it even will replace the values in your original list):

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // This is your ArrayList
    Iterator<String> it = list.iterator(); // Get your list iterator
    while(it.hasNext()){ // do a while loop to manipulate the elements
        String element = it.next(); // Get the next element of your list
        element = element.replaceFirst("^,+"); // Remove the leading comma
        it.set(element); // Replace your changed element in the list
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `startswith()` and `substring()`:

```
String[] strings = {"Jakarta, the Capital City of Indonesia.",
                ",Tokyo, the Capital City of Japan.",
                ",Manila, the Capital City of Phillipines."};
for(String str: strings){
    str = str.startsWith(",") ? str.substring(1) : str;
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String st : list)
    while (st.startsWith(","))
        st.subString(1);
```